Laptop won't start after reboot
Laptop was working very slow, so i restarted it(it asked if i want to updated and reboot, i pressed yes) After reboot it went into i initrafms mode, i used the fsck command and rebooted after that. After that the laptop won't start and is stuck here. Please help out, I am very new to linux(ubuntu)
The screen shows:
Ubuntu 22.04
[FAILED] Failed to start CUPS Scheduler.
[FAILED] Failed to start Power Profiles daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start Accounts Service.
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start Accounts Service.
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start User Manager for UID 128.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start Time & Date Service.


It was dekstops veraion initially, i guess. But i changed one setting in the update tab to main server from my countries server. Is this because of that?. I'm really noob at this and i installed ubuntu cuz my friend told me its better for older laptops to use ubuntu instead of windows.

That should not be the problem.

From your question. This is not something Ubuntu ever asks you to do. asked if i want to updated and reboot What was the setting you changed and why? Please do not answer in a comment but use edit to add the info to the question.
